# How to automatically enter date separator on libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

How to automatically enter date separator on libreoffice calc?

e.g.: I type `26112020` on a cell and when I hit `Enter` or leave the cell I would like this value to be automatically formatted/changed to `26/11/2020`. This date format is `DD/MM/YYYY` (but I think it doesn't matter, right?).

Also, it would be nice if I could do the same with time, e.g.: entering `1235` would automatically format/change to `12:35`.

I think I just need to put a `/` or a `:` in the entered value.

Thanks

Comment: No, this is a bad idea! This is a VERY bad idea! You can apply a custom format `00"/"00"/"0000` to a cell and it will look like a date, but it will not be a date, it will just remain a large number 26112020. You can try converting this to a "real date" with some tricky formulas or macros, but - believe me! - it's not worth the effort. Sooner or later, something similar to 12101109 will appear in the cell and you will have problems - is this October 12, 1109? Or is it December 10th? Or is it November 9, 1210 at all?

Comment: Better take a look at [Tools - Options - Language Settings - Languages ​​- Date acceptance patterns](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/optionen/01140000.html) - this makes data entry a lot easier: yes, you still need to enter a separator, but you can skip entering the year digits. In addition, the **Ctrl+;** will allow you to enter 26/11/2020 with just one keypress.